# Find Optimal Subset of Feature Layer Based on Spatial Criteria & Attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics, machine-learning

I'm using a Census tract shapefile with their corresponding attributes of interest within ArcMap 10.7.1.

My project goal is to identify the subset of tracts that share a line segment while:

1. maximizing the sum of unemployed people (attribute #1) AND
2. retaining an unemployment rate of less than 6.5 percent (attribute #2-this quotient will require the calculation of two other fields).

In the past, I've used tools to identify polygons that share a border, and I've used the 'Select by Attributes' tool in another project to query.

However, I'm stuck because this particular project has an interdependent set of criteria based on both spatial relationship and corresponding attributes.

How to efficiently model multiple iterations to find optimal solution?

Comment: This may be an NP problem, and might be NP Hard. This general class of problem usually requires significant computing resources to iterate each pass. Efficiency doesn't always come into play, however. You might need to try to get *any* solution, possibly with a simplified dataset, then work on optimization from there.

Comment: Thanks @Vince.  I think you may be right, there is no single, efficient solution.  I will have to work each aspect of the problem independently, and manually pull together the solution.